# `Future<Stream>` is not a subtype of type `Stream`

Tags: flutter, dart

I made simple singleton class to use on flutter `StreamBuilder` widget, for example:

```
StreamBuilder<User>(
  stream: MydbModel.create().then((dao) => dao.getUserStream()) as Stream<User>,
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    ...
  },
)
```

in that

`MydbModel.create().then((dao) => dao.getUserStream())`

return `Future<Stream<User>>` and my cast don't work to have only `Stream<User>`.

**Error:**

```
> type 'Future<Stream<User>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<User>' in type cast
```

how can i resolve this problem?

**my completed class:**

```
class MydbModel{
  UserDao _userDao;

  MydbModel._(this._userDao);
  static Future<MydbModel> create() async => MydbModel._(await initialDatabase());

  static Future<UserDao> initialDatabase() async {
    var db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db').build();
    return db.userDao;
  }

  Stream<User> getUserStream(){
    return userDao.getUserInfo();
  }

  UserDao get userDao=>_userDao;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the `Future` first:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: MydbModel.create(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MydbModel> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: snapshot.data.getUserStream(),
      builder: ..,
    );
  },
);
```

I used a `FutureBuilder` to `await` the `Future` and to create a `StreamBuilder` when the future is loaded.